# Slicing NumPy array given start and end indices for generic dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

Given a numpy array x of shape `(N_1...N_k)` where k is arbitrary, and 2 arrays :

```
start_indices=[a_1,...,a_k], end_indices=[b_1,...b_k], where `0<=a_i<b_i<=N_i`.
```

I want to slice x as follows: `x[a_1:b_1,...,a_k:b_k]`.

Lets say :

```
x is of shape `(1000, 1000, 1000)`
start_indices=[450,0,400]
end_indices=[550,1000,600].
```

I want the output to be equal `x[450:550,0:1000,400:600]`.

For example I tried to define :

```
slice_arrays = (np.arange(start_indices[i], end_indices[i]) for i in range(k))
```

and use

```
x[slice_arrays]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `arange` creates arrays, which index in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice` notation to create an indexing tuple that could be used for the indexing -

```
indexer = tuple([slice(i,j) for (i,j) in zip(start_indices,end_indices)])
out = x[indexer]
```

Alternatively, with shorthand [`np.s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) -

```
indexer = tuple([np.s_[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(start_indices,end_indices)])
```

Or with `map` for a compact one -

```
indexer = tuple(map(slice,start_indices,end_indices))
```

Comment: It worked thanks! I tried the exact same thing with just with array instead of tuple and it did not worked but this seems to fix it!

Comment: `np.s_` is not really a shorthand here, is it?  ;^)

Comment: @PaulPanzer Nah, isn't saving any characters here.