# Python/Numpy: How to extract interior of any dimension of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

Suppose I have a numpy array A which can be of any dimensions len(A.shape) can be 1,2,3,..etc. and a corresponding array, crop which len(crop) = len(A.shape) and I want to extract the interior values of A using crop. Here is an example for 2D array.

```
    A = np.random.rand(30).reshape([5,6])
    crop = np.array([1,2])
```

Wanted output:

```
    A[crop[0]:-crop[0], crop[1]:-crop[1])
```

Assuming value of crop will be reasonable with respect to size of A. How do I do this for any dimension of array A ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way with [`slice` notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) -

```
A[tuple([slice(i,-i,None) for i in crop])]
```

Or with the shorthand [`np.s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) -

```
A[tuple([np.s_[i:-i] for i in crop])]
```

If the start and end indices are given for each dimension, we can do something like as shown in [`Slicing NumPy array given start and end indices for generic dimensions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56236965/).